# Why is Jake using a regular wheelchair in the year 2154?

Tags: avatar

In the movie *Avatar* (2009), why is Jake using a regular wheelchair in the year 2154? Shouldn't exoskeletal leg braces (like the ones that Tony gave to Rhodes at the end of *Captain America: Civil War*) be cheaply available by then? How come they have huge AMP suits for combat but don't have exoskeletal leg braces?

Comment: Maybe exoskeleton leg braces are not standard issue for marines?

Comment: it wouldn't make much of a difference for the character if he could already walk from the beginning.

Comment: You can't judge one movie by another's universe, especially not a comic book superhero one. Otherwise, pretty much every movie's plot could be defeated by wondering why Superman doesn't just make an appearance.

Answer (score 3):

He couldnt afford anything better.

A big part of the relationship between Jake and Quaritch was that if he helped him out and reported on the natives then he would help him get his legs back. Seemingly the technology was available to do that but it wasnt standard issue for everyone.